# Nested Properties in Urbancode Deploy

Tags: properties, udeploy, urbancode

I am using urbancode deploy 6.2.2. Is it possible to do something like this

Say key is property name in udeploy

  key value
- p1  v1
- v1  v2

Is it possible to do something of similar nature in udeploy ${p:${p:p1}}.